# Hash history can not push state in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router-v4

I used HashRouter for setting up routes in react. I try to redirect to some other component after api call, but it shows a warning("Warning: Hash history cannot push state; it is ignored).

Routing Code

```
<HashRouter>
        <div ref={el => (this.div = el)}>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact />
            <Route path="/login" component={Register} exact />
            <Route path="/verification" component={Verification} exact />
            <Route path="/user-dashboard" component={Profile} exact />
            <Route path="/logout" component={Profile} exact />
            <Route path="/contact-us" component={Contact} exact />
            <Route path="/terms-and-conditions" render={({ match }) => <TermCondition />} exact />
            <Route path="/forgot-password" render={({ match }) => <ForgotPassword />} exact />
            <Route path="/reset/:token" render={({ match }) => <Reset token={match.params.token} />}exact />
            <Route path="/new-label" component={NewLabel} exact />
            <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
```

Axios calling where is used history.push

```
Axios.post(ApiProvider.endpoint + `/login`, loginData, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .then(result => {
                this.props.history.push('/verification', { email: this.state.email });
                toast.success(result.data.message);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                toast.error(error.response.data.message);
            })
```